Insights on Procedure in mySQL
I am trying to define a procedure that should run at midnight everyday.
CREATE PROCEDURE name
BEGIN
  do something ; 
  do something 2 ;
  do something 3 ; 
END

I understand the need for delimiter in the actual code.

How do I time this procedure so it runs at midnight everyday. I am assuming this time will be taken from the server clock. So if mySQL is running on a GCP that's on US time - the server will give that current_time() to my code.

Can the Procedure give me OUT without IN? Should I use that - or should I do such data handling with functions?

What are the restrictions on a procedure? Something(s) that I must know for my procedure to not cause looping.

Functions will return scalar values and procedures can return multiple values. is this correct?

I found a way to check if the procedure worked or not - is to check the number of rows 'affected' - would this be good?

Can the values within the procedure be used in another procedure ? Or should each procedure finish and update columns - which then gets picked up by the next procedure. What is more sensible?

Is it general practice to setup procedures on time or on calls from the client ? Suppose a dynamically changing value of a column is to be shown - I can't leave the DB open can I ? So I run the query on table column and keep it for retrieval - or should I ask PHP to fetch me the data each time the user refreshes their page? Which is a healthier option for everyone involved?


The code I am building is to work with different tables in WordPress.
The trigger activates at a particular value change in a table column. The trigger then updates newTABLE with the changed values.
Then at midnight today - the Procedure runs over this newTABLE to pickup different values from different tables - and updates the newTABLE before deleting the value of the primary key in newTABLE. This ensures the same record doesn't get updated with the procedure again tomorrow midnight.

You can run procedural code at a certain time everyday using MySQL Event Scheduler (for scheduling and execution of events). Thats a lot of questions you have in a single post. Typically one can answer a question or an issue or two in this forum. Most of your questions are already described in the MySQL Reference Documentation (or Manual). Have you referred the documentation?

Here is the documentation link for creating events: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html

After setting up a MySQL EVENT (and turning on the scheduler), come back with whatever of your 7 questions have not resolved themselves.
